# Aharonov-Bohm effect and periodic boundary conditions for particle on a ring

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, boundary-conditions, aharonov-bohm

For a particle on a ring, we have the periodic boundary conditions $\psi(\phi+2\pi)=\psi(\phi)$. If we also have a magnetic field penetrating perpendicularly the ring, then when the particle goes around the ring once, it picks up an Aharonov-Bohm phase factor equal to

$$q \dfrac{\Phi}{\hbar}$$

where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux, given by the closed line integral of the magnetic vector potential along the ring. How do we reconcile the fact that we have periodic boundary conditions and the Aharonov-Bohm (AB) phase factor?

**Note:** that while here I'm using a single particle going around a full circle, so quantities such as $|\psi(\phi)|^2$ get unaffected by the AB phase, the same argument can be done in cases where two particles at different quantum states go around a half circle at opposite directions but with the same start and end points. There, the AB effect is observable and the question of how to reconcile this with periodic BCs is valid.

Comment: Isn't this the point? You cannot gauge away the effect of $A$... in other words, you can leave the Hamiltonian as it is, with periodic boundary conditions and then $A$ will appear in the Hamiltonian (and spectrum). If you make a gauge transformation, you go from PBC to twisted periodic BC and $A$ will disappear from the Hamiltonian, but appear in the BC. You are right, such functions are in fact no (single-valued) functions, but you do not impose PBC anymore after the transformation.

Comment: @TobiasFünke it seems that in the case of my question and in the case you describe (twisted PBC), we lose the single-valuedness, which is something many authors impose.

Comment: The AB effect refers to a system where electrons move outside the region with a strong magnetic field and a shift of interference pattern proportional to magnetic flux is detected on a screen, but in your example, magnetic field is present even where the particle is (ring), so it is a different system, and there is no screen... What do you want to reconcile?

Comment: @JánLalinský the magnetic field is zero on the ring. You just have a magnetic flux inside the ring. I'm talking about the standard, elementary treatment of the AB effect found in textbooks such as Griffiths' QM

Comment: A fairly comprehensive treatment of these matters is found in [https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.13403](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.13403).

Comment: @KurtG. I'm afraid I can't find any section addressing the particulars of this question but thanks anyway!

Comment: I believe the following is explains the riddle: Dirac showed that if a single magnetic monopole exists then electric charge must be quantized in order that quantum mechanical wave functions are continuous and single valued (periodic boundary conditions). As far as a phase difference is concerned Aharonov-Bohm is not very different from a double slit experiment. In both experiments we superimpose two (continuous and single valued) wave functions and get interference from their phase difference. The different "paths" around the solenoid (resp. through the two slits) are not paths ...

Comment: ... of the particle. (The particle is a wave!). Those paths are our artefacts along which the wave function changes its phase differently.

Comment: @KurtG. I'm aware of Dirac's argument and the wavelike nature of particles, but what convinces me that the question is still valid is the fact that the Aharonov-Bohm effect is not only observable, but also a Berry phase. Moreover, it's observable. For the two paths (as Berry derived it), we have $\psi\propto e^{i\phi/2}(\psi_1+ e^{i\phi}\psi_2)$, where $\psi_i$ is the wavefunction of the particles following path $i$, $\phi$ is the AB phase. We have interference effects and it is observable (there are experiments which have measured this). Moreover, the AB phase is gauge invariant...

Comment: ... and it cannot be gauged away. We can try to gauge away one of the phase factors obtained in either path, but then the wavefunction of the other path will get a contribution from the gauge transformation. If the total path is closed, the AB phase cannot be gauged away. You can find an elementary treatment of this in the AB section of Griffiths' QM textbook.

Comment: In the Note in OP you mention paths of particles and that was exactly what I was questioning. Quantum mechanical particles don't follow paths. We knew that decades before AB. AB is an interference experiment just like the double slit. The novel thing in it is that the interference depends on the vector potential $A$ even if its curl (magnetic field $B$) is zero.

Comment: @KurtG. Paths of particles was loosely put, but what I mean is just the "usual" problem of two split beams that meet at two points and in the middle of them, their joint paths enclose a magnetic flux.

Answer (score 1):

I am not completely sure I understand why you think there is a contradiction between the periodic boundary conditions and the fact that the wavefunction picks up an Aharonov-Bohm phase factor, but I'll take a stab at it.

From the comments I gather you feel that the periodic boundary condition on the wavefunction is sufficient to impose a fundamental symmetry on the system, and that the presence of the AB phase factor contradicts this. But in fact the periodic boundary condition (combined with an expectation of continuity) are only sufficient to impose quantisation on a certain parameter that appears in the solution of the Schrödinger equation (which also implies quantisation of the energy).

In addition, note that the magnetic field lifts the two-fold degeneracy of the particle in a ring (the magnetic field/current introduces a directionality).

Instead of the case with no magnetic field anywhere, where the energy is given by $\frac{n^2 \hbar^2}{2mR^2}$, the energies are now $\frac{\hbar^2}{2mR^2}(n - \frac{q\Phi}{2\pi\hbar})^2$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $R$ is the radius of the ring.

So *even though the magnetic field at the particle is always 0* there is, in fact, a difference between the particle going 'with' or 'against' the current, and this is reflected in the distinct energy eigenvalues. Viewed in this way picking up a phase after a revolution doesn't seem so strange (although the AB effect certainly does, upon first encountering it).

**Edit - 13/9/2023**

I have given this more thought. Firstly, the magnetic flux isn't quantised. It would be if we were dealing with a superconducting ring, but that is a different situation.

Secondly, as you already know, a pure phase change doesn't have any physically observable effect by itself - the expectation values don't change, generally speaking.

I think the fact that this is troubling you is a pointer that you should read e.g. chapter 9.1 of Atland and Simons (as mentioned in the comments). I will attempt to summarise the relevant pieces here.

Basically, there are topological considerations at play. The $n$ that appears in the expression for the energy is a winding number. The $\phi$ parameter can be elevated to a field, such that the Lagrangian of the system is given by $L(\phi, \dot{\phi}) = \frac{1}{2} \dot{\phi}^2 - iA \dot{\phi}$. This permits a path integral formulation, where the path integral  boundary condition is such that the phase is only defined up to integer multiples of $2 \pi$ (see below for screenshot from the textbook).

[image: winding number]

You can perform a gauge transformation at each angle by $\psi(\phi) \rightarrow e^{i\frac{q\Phi}{2\pi \hbar}\phi}\psi(\phi)$, so that one revolution corresponds to $e^{i\frac{q\Phi}{\hbar}}\psi(\phi)$ (the AB phase factor). This is a gauge transformation of the Schrödinger equation with the Hamiltonian of classical electrodynamics (see e.g. exercise 4.61b in the 2nd edition of Griffiths' QM book). If I have performed the correct calculation, this should change the boundary condition to $\psi(0) = e^{i\frac{q\Phi}{\hbar}}\psi(2\pi)$.

Maybe take this with a grain of salt (I welcome being corrected by someone more knowledgeable), and have a look at chapter 9.1 of Atland and Simons. You should be able to find a copy online. My apologies if this is more confusing than helpful, but I quite enjoyed reading up on the topic, so thank you for the question.

Comment: I understand the magnetic field lifting the degeneracy, but, respectfully, I don't think this answers my question. The wavefunction picks up the AB phase. This phase is not gauge invariant when going around a full circle on the ring. So, it seems like a wavefunction picking up the AB phase can only satisfy the periodic boundary conditions $\psi(2\pi)=\psi(0)$ is to quantise the magnetic flux. This doesn't seem intuitive to me, as we're imposing the quantisation of an external quantity in order to reconcile the AB phase and the periodic BCs.

Comment: Ok. I'll spend some more time thinking about it, maybe I can come up with something better.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan just to clarify - why do you say "this phase is not gauge invariant when going around a full circle on the ring"? Isn't the point that the AB phase IS gauge invariant?

Comment: Yes, I mistakenly written the opposite. It;s gauge invariant (otherwise my whole argument doesn't hold)

Comment: @TheQuantumMan I have done my best to provide a more convincing answer. Perhaps the last sentence specifically should answer your question (something similar was alluded to in the comments).

Comment: Many thanks. I think the issue lies in your last sentence. How does it change the boundary conditions? Because, after a full revolution, picking up the extra phase (due to "winding" once), imposing that the periodic conditions are met (at $2\pi$ we have the wavefunction with the extra phase and at $0$ we have the original) will lead to a quantisation of the external flux, which is what I disagree with, physically. So, it all depends on how the boundary conditions change

Comment: @TheQuantumMan I have updated the answer. I have a feeling you will not be satisfied, but I'm afraid that's the best I have.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a charged particle on a ring then you combine both conditions, yielding:
\begin{equation}
\frac{q}{h}\Phi = 2\pi n
\end{equation}
Where $n$ is an integer thus you have a quantisation of the flux threading the ring.
This effect is present in superconducting rings for example ([Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux_quantum)).

Comment: But why do we have to impose conditions on an external field in order to satisfy this?

Comment: Also, in the case of 2 beams meating that I described in the note in my question, the AB effect is observable, whereas with this quantisation condition, even in that case the AB effect seems not to matter.

Comment: @TheQuantumMan It's not so much that we impose a condition on $\Phi$ but rather that this is the only way to satisfy the assumptions you put in your model. If you remove, let's say the periodicity of the boundary conditions then this quantization disappears, for example.

Comment: So how is the AB effect observable in an experimental setup corresponding to this system? Because we do know it's measurable in such a case

Comment: You could definitely model the observation of the AB effect but you would have to extend the model a bit. Experimentally one way (for example) would be to connect the ring to two reservoirs and measure the transmission of this apparatus. Theoretically you now want to compute scattering amplitudes instead of eigen-energies since your system is not closed and confined anymore (so no more forced flux quantization).
If you compute the current $I$ of such device as a function of the flux $\Phi$ you should find that it's periodic (and continuous), this periodicity is a signature of the AB effect.

Comment: But, what I'm talking about is pretty elementary. The same treatment (along with the conclusions on observability) is found in textbooks such as Griffiths' QM one. But they never talk about the AB phase in relation to the boundary conditions.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, see *Altland & Simons, 2nd Edition, Chapter 9*: "Note that the literature is full of erroneous statements on even this simple system. The most frequent of these is that the periodic boundary conditions of the problem force the flux to be quantized in integer multiples of the flux quantum Φ = nΦ0. This is, of course, incorrect. Even for non-integer Φ, the wavefunctions φn are perfectly periodic. The statement is probably triggered by flux-quantization in superconducting systems (a phenomenon that relies on energetic, and not topological, considerations)."